# Hibernate CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and multi-entity transactions in MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I have two different entities (A & B) declared with JPA and are persisted with Hibernate (mysql 5.6.30, Hibernate 3.6.8 and Spring 4.2.1) in the same transaction. Both entities contains this column:

```
`created_at` DATETIME(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)
```

When I create A & B in the same transaction `created_at` will be different for A & B.

My test is using Spring and is defined something like this:

```
@Autowired
private TransactionTemplate inTx;

@Test
public void test() {
    inTx.execute(__ -> {
       aRepository.add(a);
       bRepository.add(b);
       return null;
    });
}
```

I'm quite sure that the entities are in the same transaction since the `add` metod in both `aRepository` and `bRepository` is defined annotated like this:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
```

I've also tried changing the test to look something like this:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    inTx.execute(__ -> {
       aRepository.add(a);
       Thread.sleep(1000);
       bRepository.add(b);
       return null;
    });
}
```

And this yields a result like this:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: [A and B should have the same timestamp]
Expecting:
 <[2016-05-09T14:16:28.531,
   2016-05-09T14:16:28.532]>
to contain only:
 <[2016-05-09T14:16:28.531]>
but the following elements were unexpected:
 <[2016-05-09T14:16:28.532]>
```

I.e. the timestamp are very close but not the same. My intuition would suggest that `created_at` for A & B would be *exactly* the same since they are a part of the same transaction. So my questions are:

1. Is this expected behavior or am I doing something wrong?
2. If this is expected behavior, is there are way to persist the transaction end-time instead of entity creation time? (so that the `created_at` timestamp will be the same for all entities persisted in the same transaction)

Comment: 1. Yes (but might differ on different databases), 2. Not that I'm aware of, unless you use a trigger or something like that.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe you can add it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is indeed expected behavior. As soon as the item is inserted into the database the value will be set (if it isn't set before hand). Hence depending on the speed of your server there probably will be a difference.

If you want to use the database to control this your best bet is a trigger which updates the times based on the transaction ending.

You could also do it in Java by setting the current date before inserting. Create a date instance once and set that on all entities. That way the database default won't kick in.